# VSTO Word WindowBeforeRightClick event's Cancel parameter getting ignored by images context menu

Tags: c#, ms-word, office365, vsto

I am attempting to create my own context menu that shows when Word is in a custom 'mode'. To do this I want to disable all default context menus in favour of mine. This works perfectly when right-clicking text but not when right-clicking images or text boxes (seems to be objects in general). It looks like the event's Cancel parameter gets ignored when images are right-clicked, therefore it doesn't stop Word's context menu from showing.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Word?

Does anyone have a solution for globally adding context menu items and hiding the rest?

Alternatives to my goal might also be the solution.

I have tried to use ribbon.xml but there are many different context menus with many different buttons, galleries etc which I would have to actively hide. Plus, I would have to duplicate a lot of XML to add my buttons to all these menus. In this pursuit, I have found the documentation for listing these context menu items lacking a complete list which has left me hunting for button idMso's. Also, if Microsoft were to add a new item, I would then have to release an update to actively remove the new item. The whole ribbon.xml way of dealing with context menus is a very difficult way of achieving what should be a simple request (in my opinion).

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    internal bool CustomContextMenuMode = true;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ThisAddIn.WordApplication.WindowBeforeRightClick += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(Application_WindowBeforeRightClick);
    }

    private static void Application_WindowBeforeRightClick(Word.Selection Sel, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (CustomContextMenuMode == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Context menu shows here!");
            Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

If you right-click text (with or without a selection range), a table, or many other things, you will see that the message box shows. And when dismissed, the Cancel parameter prevents the default context menu from showing.

However, when an image is right-clicked, it shows the message box (like before) but when dismissed it still shows Word's image context menu.

Here is my Word version:

Office 365 Business,
Word version 1903 (build 11425.20204) or v16.0.11425.20200

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug. Even if you go the Ribbon XML route, there are some things you can't disable in 2013+: Style/Crop. They can be disabled but not removed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was hoping this was not the case, but it is what it is. Hopefully Microsoft will fix it some day!